# Pymongo error connecting to mongodb via atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to establish a connection to my mongodb database via atlas and pymongo. I am connecting my application using the connection string given from atlas page, and everything seems to be working fine. I can connect to my database but then I get an error message when I try to count how many entries are in my database/retrieve/send data to atlas.

```
import pymongo
import dns

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:<password>@storedinputs-vc4cl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true")
db = client.get_database("dbname")
records = db.collectiontable

count = records.count_documents({})
print(count)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issue
r certificate (_ssl.c:1056),storedinputs-shard-00-00-vc4cl.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] cer
tificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Again I've tried it line by line and everything works fine until I try and count the amount of documents in my collection. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 6):

Try with

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:<password>@storedinputs-vc4cl.mongodb.net/test", ssl=True,ssl_cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add '`&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE`' to the db string and it will work fine !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [troubleshooting section](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors) in PyMongo documentation, it covers the issue you are experiencing together with possible solutions.

Comment: This thread references an install file for OSX users which is no longer present in Catalina.   Gggggrrrrrr!!! Has anyone solved this?